# C semaphore not locking as intended

Tags: c, locking, semaphore

I have been attempting to learn semaphores with this simple ticket selling program. The only issue is that the semaphore in place currently isn't protecting the value of `numTickets` and `ticketsSold`. I found this because sometimes the total tickets sold will add up to 51.

**Is the proper implementation of a semaphore?**

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int numTickets;
sem_t mySem;

void* sell_ticket(void *sellerNum) {
  int sell = (int) sellerNum;
  int ticketsSold = 0;

  while (numTickets > 0) {
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int random_number = rand();
    for (int i = 1; i < random_number % 5 ; i++) {
      if (numTickets > 0) {
        sem_wait(&mySem);
        numTickets--;
        ticketsSold++;
        printf("Seller # %d  sold a ticket. Tickets left: %d\n", sell, numTickets);
        sem_post(&mySem);
      }
    }
  }
  printf("Seller #%d noticed all tickets sold! (I sold %d myself) \n", sell, ticketsSold);
}

int main() {
  numTickets = 50;
  int numSellers = 4;
  sem_init(&mySem, 0, 1);

  pthread_t sellerThread;

  for (int i = 0; i < numSellers; i++) {
    pthread_create(&sellerThread, NULL, sell_ticket, (void *)i);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < numSellers; i++) {
    pthread_join(sellerThread, NULL);
  }
  printf("All tickets sold!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm no kind of pthreads expert, but expect that reading numTickets (in the `if` and `while`) when another thread is writing it is the problem. You need to get the read-modify-write sequence inside the semaphore-protected block.

Comment: I have tried the above suggestion. Sadly i got a value of 51 after various tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I can see two problems with your code:

1) Since you are starting more than one thread (one thread per seller) you should have an array of p_threads, not just a single one. Otherwise, pthread_join will not join all the created threads, but only the last one (since each time you create a new thread, you are overwriting the handle to the previously created one)

Your main should look similar to the following:

```
int main() {
  numTickets = 50;
  int numSellers = 4;
  sem_init(&mySem, 0, 1);

  pthread_t sellerThread[4];

  for (int i = 0; i < numSellers; i++) {
    pthread_create(&sellerThread[i], NULL, sell_ticket, (void *)i);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < numSellers; i++) {
    pthread_join(sellerThread[i], NULL);
  }
  printf("All tickets sold!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

2) Additionally, like Gene correctly commented already, you need to use the semaphore to read the number of tickets as well (in the `if` and `while` condition test). Otherwise you could still end up with a case where one thread is writing, and another one is reading.

However note that taking the semaphore for the whole loop duration will result in only one thread selling all the tickets.

Therefore the sell_ticket function should look similar to this:

```
void* sell_ticket(void *sellerNum) {
  int sell = (int) sellerNum;
  int ticketsSold = 0;

  while (true) {
    // Check the number of tickets left. If sold out break out of infinite loop
    sem_wait(&mySem);
    if (numTickets <= 0) {
      sem_post(&mySem);
      break;
    }
    sem_post(&mySem);

    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int random_number = rand();
    for (int i = 1; i < random_number % 5 ; i++) {
      // Wait for semaphore before reading numTickets value in if condtion
      sem_wait(&mySem);

      if (numTickets > 0) {
        numTickets--;
        ticketsSold++;
        printf("Seller # %d  sold a ticket. Tickets left: %d\n", sell, numTickets);
      }
       // Post after if
       sem_post(&mySem);
    }
  }
  printf("Seller #%d noticed all tickets sold! (I sold %d myself) \n", sell, ticketsSold);
}
```

Comment: I have read through your answer and I do see now how putting semaphores around my if and while is a smart option. Sadly, even with the code provided. I occasionally get values higher than 50.